# An unexpected error has occurred (-2147467259) when Importing spreadsheet

Tags: error, excel, import, spreadsheet

I trying to Import from Spreadsheet to create a list and the above error occurs - the site is trusted and office activated - I have tried various spreadsheets so its not a number of cells issue. Can anyone assist please.

A month ago, I installed SharePoint Designer 2007 to test something and since then the import stopped working.

Comment: Do you any other office 2003/2010/2013 installed also?

Comment: ONLY office 2010, but I have sharepoint designer 2007, and 2010

Answer (score 1):

Try repairing your office 2010 installation I have seen over the years issues with the owssupp.dll which handles SharePoint and Offfice integration. It might be that now the 2007 version is being run instead of the 2010 version.

Answer (score 0):

The error code -2147467259 (0x80004005) does not signify much, microsoft just lists it as an unspecified error / failure. See for example [COM Error codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/com-error-codes-1).

If you have access to the SharePoint Server log files, you may find additional information there.

Also, make sure to save the spreadsheet in the XML format (xls**x**).